# How to Solve Overscan issues on Nvidia GX?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display-resolution

[In windows] I solve it with CRU (Custom Resolution Utility) By unticking the "Include extension block" box.

[I assume that has something to do with UEID], but im only guessing.
But that does completely solve it.

--> What is the Ubuntu/Linux equivilent of doing this in Ubuntu, so i can use my HDMI without X messing up window placement, toolbars, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with modelines and `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, `xrandr` and `cvt`:

1. Use `cvt $X_RES $Y_RES` to get the "modeline" [substitute with your resolution]
2. Use `xrandr --newmode output` to add the modeline. `$output` is the output of `cvt` *without* the 'Modeline' keyword in front of it. The first parameter after 'Modeline' you could consider the "name" of the modeline. Maybe add a suffix to it to denote that it's using custom values.
3. `xrandr --addmode $name $current_output`
   run `xrandr` to find the name of the current output (VGA-1, DP0, or similar)
4. `xrandr --output VGA1 --mode $name`

***NOTE:*** This will only last for this session. To make this permanent and also for more details, see here:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr#Adding_undetected_resolutions

In case you have access to a correct EDID, you can also specify this instead of adding modelines manually as I wrote here:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA_Optimus#Resolution.2C_screen_scan_wrong._EDID_errors_in_Xorg.log

In that case I had access to the EDID via another driver - that's why I had that path.